# Инкрементировать последнее число в строке, разделённой точками

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

Как увеличить patch версию в GIT тэге через BASH скрипт?

Пример

```
last_tag="1.00.09"
res=`expr match "$last_tag" '\.\(\[0-9\]$\)'`
echo $res
```

Эта регулярка не работает.
Нужно получить

```
last_tag="1.00.10"
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? В каком месте кода вы пытаетесь заменить "09" на "10"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
last_tag="1.00.09"   
last_tag="$(awk -F '.' '{print $1"."$2"."$3+1}' <<<$last_tag)"
```

Или так

```
last_tag="$(${last_tag%.*}.$( expr ${last_tag##*.} + 1 ))"
```

> Но оба варианта будут работать только для последнего сегмента

А так будет работать пока не устанет, отделяя точками два последних сегмента по 2 цифры

```
last_tag="1.00.09"
d="$(( ${last_tag//.} + 1 ))"
last_tag="${d::${#d}-4}"."${d:${#d}-4:2}"."${d:${#d}-2:2}"
```

**UPD**
С учетом сделанных замечаний и подсказок. Можно нумеровать начиная с 0.00.00

```
last_tag="1.00.09"

f="${last_tag//.}"
[[ ${f::1} -eq 0 ]] && add=1
b="${add}${f}"
(( b++ ))
[[ ${f::1} -eq 0 ]] && b="${b:1}"

next_tag="${b::${#b}-4}.${b:${#b}-4:2}.${b:${#b}-2:2}"
echo "$next_tag"
# 1.00.10
```

Comment: вопрос-то был про интерпретатор *bash*, а не *awk*.

Comment: Ну так вроде и без awk дал вариантов. Просто awk первое что пришло в голову. Второй так вообще кристально чистый bash

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

`09` — некорректная запись **восьмиричного** числа.

если бы число было десятичное, то достаточно:

```
v="1.0.9"
res=${v%.*}.$((${v##*.}+1))
```

а в случае некорректной записи надо сначала удалить лишний ноль, для чего (на языке, понятном интерпретатору *bash*) потреубется промежуточная переменная:

```
v="1.0.09"
l=${v##*.}
res=${v%.*}.$((${l##0}+1))
```

Comment: @AndreyKarpov, насколько я в курсе, язык, понимаемый интерпретатором *bash*, тьюринг-полный. так что: да, можно.

Comment: Извиняюсь, за то, что удалил свой комментарий на который Вы ответили, сам просто уже допетрил

Comment: @AndreyKarpov, подсказка: чтобы не «выёживаться» с некорректно-написанными восьмиричными числами, можно, например, приписывать в начало символ "1", а потом его удалять.

Comment: И это верно!!! Спасибо